# Getting (0,0) instead of the intersecting co-ordinates value

Tags: pyqgis, coordinates, qgis-2, python-2.7

This code works below fine when line(The Circle I mean) intersects more than two new lines but fails when both the intersection falls in the middle of the same line

```
polygon_path = iface.activeLayer()
        line_path = buffers_dir+"/bufferline"+ str(i.id()) +".shp"
        #Converting the buffer features to lines
        processing.runandload("qgis:polygonstolines",polygon_path,line_path)
        linebuffer=iface.activeLayer()
        selections=[]  # The id of he intersected path of the network layer
        for f in layer.getFeatures():
            for a in linebuffer.getFeatures():
                print(a,'This is A')
                if a.geometry().intersects(f.geometry()):
                    #Finds the intersection of line buffers with network layer
                    intersection = a.geometry().intersection(f.geometry())
                    #same result with .within() and even with a and f switched (the docs aren't that clear on that)
                    print(intersection.asPoint())
                    instersection_point = intersection.asPoint()
                    connecting_points.append(instersection_point) #Contains the (X,Y) co-ordinates of intersection points
                    selections.append( f['WVK_ID'] )
```

[image]

Expected result is something like this:

```
((114041,400590), ' This is intersection')
([228201037.0, 227201083.0, 228201038.0, 228200076.0, 228201026.0, 227200047.0, 227201082.0], ' This is Selections')
```

The result i got is:

```
((0,0), ' This is intersection')
([227200062.0], ' This is Selections')
```

Error Occured:

```
  File "<string>", line 186, in <module>
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGISWI~1\apps\Python27\lib\random.py", line 274, in choice
    return seq[int(self.random() * len(seq))]  # raises IndexError if seq is empty
IndexError: list index out of range
```